# jQuery looping animation jumps past animations

Tags: jquery

First, I tried to create a looping animation like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KrisBraun/2ReGy/1/):

```
function rotator() {
  $('#foo').stop(true).delay(500).fadeIn('slow').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow',rotator);
}
$('#foo').hide();
rotator();​
```

This appears to skip the delay after the first iteration.

So I tried this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KrisBraun/bW4GX/):

```
function rotator() {
  $('#foo').stop(true).delay(500).fadeIn('slow').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow',rotator);
}
$('#foo').hide();
rotator();​
```

In this case, the fadeIn appears to jump straight to show after the first iteration.

I'm stumped. All these operations should be part of the fx queue. And even if there weren't, I can't explain why a fadeIn would change to a show. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this more of the affect you're looking for:

```js
function rotator() {
    $( '#foo' ).delay( 500 ).fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
        $( this ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 'slow', rotator );
    });
}
$('#foo').hide();
rotator();
```

Update: Figure I should explain why you're code was having problems. In jQuery, animations are asynchronous (i.e. non-blocking). So your code was queuing the animations at the same time, but just not to run until sometime in the future. You have to run the following animation in the callback, to ensure that it doesn't fire until the previous animation has completed.

Another Update: Just tried the following code and it seemed to work. Give it a shot:

```js
function rotator() {
    $( '#foo' ).delay( 500 ).fadeIn( 'slow' ).delay( 2500 ).fadeOut( 'slow', rotator );
}
$('#foo').hide();
rotator();
```

Give it a go and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, that works, and the explanation helps. I had thought all queue operations were placed in the fx queue, so my chained functions would have enqueued the whole chain to run sequentially. I think I'm still missing something, though. Why can delay and fadeIn be chained, while the subsequent fadeOut must be done through a callback rather than on the fx queue?

Comment: just updated with a snippet that's similar to yours, but seems to work for me. let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: The second update does work, which is nearly what I had to start, making the issue perfectly clear. It was my call to stop in the callback that was somehow messing with/corrupting the animation queue, which isn't all that surprising when I think about it. I'll just move that logic outside the callback for the other cases where I need it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first thought is that the fadeIn/fadeOuts are asynchronous..so you'd go immediately to the next chained command.

For example, in your first set of code, if you did this:

```
function rotator() {
    $('#foo').stop(true).delay(500).fadeIn('slow', function(){
        $('#foo').delay(2500).fadeOut('slow',rotator);
    })
}
$('#foo').hide();
rotator();​
```

You would see your 2500ms delay.